# ошибка в @bot.callback_query_handler(func = lamda call: True)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Делал своего первого **Telegram**-бота, вот отрывок кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['bet'])
def bet(message):
    bet_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    winner = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Победитель', callback_data = 'winner')
    total = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Тотал', callback_data = 'total')
    score = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Точный счет', callback_data = 'score')

    bet_markup.add(winner, total, score) 

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выбери тип ставки: ', reply_markup = bet_markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lamda call: True)
def bet_answer(call):
    if call.data == 'winner':
        winner_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        winner1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'П1', callback_data = 'winner1')
        draw = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'X', callback_data = 'draw')
        winner2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'П2', callback_data = 'winner2')

        winner_markup.add(winner1, draw, winner2)

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выбери победителя', reply_markup = winner_markup)

    elif call.data == 'total':
        total_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

        BO1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Best Of 1', callback_data = 'BO1')
        BO3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Best Of 3', callback_data = 'BO3')
        BO5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Best Of 5', callback_data = 'BO5')

        total_markup.add(BO1, BO3, BO5)

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Выберите тип Best Of', reply_markup = total_markup)
    elif call.data == 'score':
        score_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()

        BO1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Best Of 1', callback_data = 'BO1')
        BO3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Best Of 3', callback_data = 'BO3')
        BO5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Best Of 5', callback_data = 'BO5')

        score_markup.add(BO1, BO3, BO5)
```

При запуске программа выдаёт ошибку. Вот её текст:

```
File "TLBbot.py", line 52
    @bot.callback_query_handler(func = lamda, call: True)
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Я в этом новичок, так что прошу, пожалуйста, объяснить всё на пальцах

Comment: просто в видео одном обучающем увидел, говорю же я новичок и не шарю в этом(

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй этот код:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c: True)
```

Также еще можно без `func=`, но это только на aiogram вроде.

Comment: оказалось все куда проще - я в слове lambda пропустил букву b и сидел мучался) вставил ваш вариант и сравнил с моим, так и понял что пропустил букву